# Math: 3 rotating dials with 3 values that should always = 100%

Tags: javascript, math

I have three dials: D1, D2 and D3. Together their values should always be 100% and their default Values are 50%, 25% and 25% respectively.

When a user edits D2 or D3, D1 should act as the FIRST pot to pull from and Deposit to.

**Here is the problem**: what if the editable dials are increased past the point of D1 reserves? I need to find a way to have the the remaining pull from the dial not being edited at that moment.

I guess I am looking for a elegant solution as opposed to a hack. Any one got such a solution?

http://jsfiddle.net/cborgia/ByWCA/

Comment: Just move the other two by half the change of the one the user's moving.

Comment: I asked my question without the detail needed to explain why that is not sufficient. I will edit to further explain the concept of dial 1 acting as a "reserve")

Comment: @ChristopherBorgia—if you can't explain the logic for the dial values, it will be a guessing game for those who wish to help.

Comment: Just move D1 to its limit, then move the other dial to take up the remaining change. You don't really have any more elegant options.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is solve an equation of three functions like:

```
X + Y +  Z = K;
```

where:

```
X = x + a(dx)
Y = y + b(dy)
Z = z + c(dz)
K = 100
```

and

1. `a`, `b` and `c` are functions
2. `x`, `y` and `z` are the current values of the knobs and
3. `dx`, `dy` and `dz` are the changes in knob values

The functions are solved given values for K (always 100) and one of `X`, `Y` and `Z` where `X`, `Y` and `Z` are in the range 0 to 100 inclusive.

You don't say what should happen as `X`, `Y` and `Z` approach 0 or 100 - are they proportionally reduced, or is the excess or deficit applied to the other non–user adjusted knob?

Comment: Thanks @RobG for given me the direction to start working in. I'm taking a crack at it now.

Comment: Christopher, this is normally addressed using differential calculus and related rates since you will have one equation with two unknowns that must satisfy other equations. You can likely get a reasonable solution by estimating one of the unknowns and solving for the other. That will only get you close, so use the result to make a better estimate and go again and so on until it's close enough.

Comment: Nope. It's kicking my BUTT. no mater what I do they do not react the way I am intending them too. I'll keep trying, but if you have any more advice, it would help out a lot (oh and proportionally reduced is what I am going for).